# Why does one sometimes have to go through two subsequent security gates at El Alto International Airport (LPB, La Paz, Bolivia)?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, bolivia, lpb

I took a flight from El Alto International Airport (LPB, La Paz, Bolivia) to Alejandro Velasco Astete Airport (CUZ, Cusco, Peru), and passengers for this flight (boarding gate R20) were required to go through two security gates that directly followed each other, while for some other flights passengers didn't have to go through the second security gate.

Why does one sometimes have to go through two subsequent security gates at El Alto International Airport (LPB, Lima, Peru)?

That seemed redundant as the second security gate was only scanning the passengers' luggage while the first security gate was scanning passengers' luggage and bodies, but I'm assuming there is a good reason for it. The second security gate didn't require passengers to remove anything from the luggage before the scan.

Comment: I believe you have a small mixup in the second reference to the airport in the second paragraph.

Comment: Maybe the second check was not for security but for other reasons and used a different type of scanner to check for specific types of goods, e.g. drugs? Don't think that would be appropriate here but like the scans for organic matter at quarantine checks when arriving in Australia?

Comment: Or maybe they are testing new scanners.

Comment: I think @Willeke is right. Now on some airports we can keep stuffs in the bag. So I assume they are trying the new scanners. Probably for "certifying" it, they need test with real passengers and bags.

Comment: only vaguely related but I wonder if LPB-CUZ has some kind of record for (altitude of departure airport + altitude of arrival airport) of any flight / any international flight / something like that.